# Magento 2 public key and private key no longer accepted as credentials

Tags: magento, composer-php, credentials

My Magento 2 **public key** and **private key** no longer work as credentials for download. They worked yesterday and before, but not today. When I try to download Magento 2 with Composer today, now I get a

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
```

As I said, it worked yesterday. Well, because the credentials didn't work today, I signed in to Magento today, deleted the keys and created a new pair of "Secure Keys". Guess what. They won't work either. Same error message as above thrown by the Composer, when I try a "composer create-project ..."

I did not abuse Magento's service. I'm just a beginner who does multiple Magento 2 installs (always on the same machine), trying to get Magento running. When I encounter a Magento problem, I try to solve it, delete Magento and try a fresh install. So I don't suppose to be blocked or whatever.

Why are my public key / private key credentials no longer working?

Comment: It looks like it is a temporary problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Magento said there are issues with repo.magento.com
You will have some news about it in this ticket as soon as it's resolved:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4617
https://twitter.com/MagentoDevDocs/status/734357914492805120

Comment: Please don't just link to stuff, these links could go down, so your answer would be useless. It's better to include the relevant information in your answer and the you can add a link either as reference or for further information.